# PowerBI - Change visual type based on Slider

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to change the visual type based on a slider?

Let's say from lines to bar chart?

I don't have any example as I really don't know if this is possible.

Comment: You can achieve this using bookmarks and a buttons